# “We are (the) Microsoft team.” Do we need an article here?

Tags: articles

On the one hand, “Microsoft” is a name, but on the other, this team is one of a kind.
Does the answer depend on whether we are talking about the entire staff of the company or just some sports team (say Microsoft soccer team)?

Comment: They can say "we are **the** Microsoft team". They could also say "we are Team Microsoft".

Comment: But can we say "We are Microsoft team"? (To me it sounds awkward, but my friend disagrees.)

Comment: It only sounds awkward to someone whose native language does not use such articles.

Comment: So, is it also correct?

Comment: "We are the Microsoft team" is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *title* of the group were *Microsoft Team*, then this would be fine:

> We are Microsoft Team.

But note the capitalization, which is critical in this construction. Also, even though it would be correct, it would still sound a little strange. Titles of groups don't often include *Team* at the end. (In fact, I can't think of any actual examples.)

However, when the word *team* is just a common noun, and used in lowercase, then you need the article:

> We are the Microsoft team.

This is because the proper noun is acting to modify the common noun. In other respects, the sentence is constructed as if the proper noun weren't being used:

> ✘ We are team.
>   ✔ We are the team.

Note that it may also be possible to use the indefinite article or a pronoun. But there can't be nothing at all when *team* is a common noun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

*The* is used when

- the question "which X?" would make sense,
- the speaker/writer expects the listener/reader to already know which X that the speaker/writer is talking about.

  - Typical reasons for the speaker/writer to expect this are:

    - X was mentioned earlier in conversation,
    - X is a thing known to everyone,
    - X is believed to be a thing known to everyone or is trying to create that impression,
    - there is only one possible X in the world.